# Custom Authentication Still Requires Login to Admin Site

Tags: python, django

I am creating a custom user model with the ability to use a username or email to login. I have created a custom login function and can normally login into the website but it still requires me to login again when I try to access the admin site (even though the user has admin privileges).

Any idea what might be the issue?

User Model

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table='auth_user'
```

Backend

```
class BothAuthBackend(object):
    def authenticate(self, loginDetail=None, password=None):
        
        try:
            user = UserModel.objects.get(email=loginDetail)
        except:
            user = None

        if user == None:
            try:
                user = UserModel.objects.get(username=loginDetail)
            except:
                user = None

        try:
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return UserModel.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

View Function

```
def login(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = LoginForm2()
        return render(request,'users/login.html',{'form': form})
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm2(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user = BothAuthBackend.authenticate(request, loginDetail=username, password=password)
            
            if user is not None:  
                return render(request,'users/afterLogin.html')
            else:           
                return render(request, 'users/login.html', {'form': LoginForm2()})
        else:
            form = LoginForm2()
            return render(request,'users/login.html',{'form': form})
```

Settings

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend','users.backends.BothAuthBackend']
```

Answer (score 0):

Found my own solution,

Need to import this in views (and change the view function name)

```
from django.contrib.auth import login
```

Then in the view method

```
if user is not None:         
      login(request,user) 
      return redirect('users:afterLogin')
```

Also only need the 'users.backends.BothAuthBackend' in the settings file